# python 3.8 flask log dosn't print to console only to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, logging, console

i have this simple code running in flask  i want to make it print to console and to file
currently i can only to file .
the code :

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS
from Handlers import Handlers



app = Flask(__name__)
# logging.basicConfig(filename='record.log',
#                 level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(threadName)s : %(message)s')


CORS(app, supports_credentials=True,resources=r'/*'
        ,methods=['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        ,allow_headers=["Accept","Authorization","Content-Type","X-CSRF-Token"])

app.logger.info("Start broker-service port %s",71)
@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def handleBroker():
    handlers = Handlers()  
    return handlers.broker()

@app.route('/handle',methods=['POST'])
def handleSubmission():
    handlers = Handlers()  
    return handlers.handleSubmission()


if __name__  == '__main__':
    logger = logging.getLogger('dev')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(threadName)s : %(message)s')

    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
    fileHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    consoleHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    app.logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
    app.logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

    app.run(host="localhost", port=71, debug=True)
```